How to use Apache POI to read VBA
Is it possble to actually get at the macro code as text, not just the entire project as a Blob.
I have a need to scan many on a server. Not using COM.
The file VBA format is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-ovba/575462ba-bf67-4190-9fac-c275523c75fc But it is rather obtuse!

Apache POI provides VBAMacroReader. This can be used to get all the content in vbaProject.bin in decompressed textual form.
Example:
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.macros.VBAMacroReader;

class ReadXLSMVBA {
        
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  VBAMacroReader vbaMacroReader = new VBAMacroReader(new FileInputStream("./XLSMWithVBA.xlsm"));
  java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String> allMacros = vbaMacroReader.readMacros();
  for (String key : allMacros.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(key);   
   String content = allMacros.get(key);
   System.out.println(content);
  }
 }
}


Thank you.  It was not obvious to me that it would produce the actual text of the macros.
